# Listen for backup creation in Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have a Log4j appender like this:

```
<appender name="MyAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
   <param name="File"   value="logs/logfile.log" />
   <param name="Append" value="true" />
   <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2" />
   <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB" />
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="patternBlahBlahBlah"/>
   </layout>
</appender>
```

I want to backup the logs backup (`logfile.log.1`, `logfile.log.2`, ...) copying them on a DB.

There is a way to add a listener to listen for the moment when Log4j create the backup file, so I don't have to periodically check the logs directory?

Comment: If you are on a Linux/Unix system with logrotate and if the following may be an option, you could use its capability to rotate the files (instead of using log4j) and its capability to execute post rotation commands

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Windows :/ and I have to use log4j :/